# Why doesn't this PHP recursive function return the value?

Tags: php, arrays, function, recursion

I was working on an API for ustream which returns the following array

```
Array
(
[results] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 33756327
                [userName] => sachintaware
                [title] => Mobile record
                [protected] => 
                [description] => Recorded on my Android phone.
                [createdAt] => 2013-06-03 03:29:38
                [rating] => 0.000
                [lengthInSecond] => 371.544
                [totalViews] => 5
                [codecIsForLiveHttp] => 
                [url] => http://www.ustream.tv/recorded/33756327
                [embedTag] => 
                [liveHttpUrl] => 
                [imageUrl] => Array
                    (
                        [small] => http://static-cdn2.ustream.tv/videopic/0/1/33/33756/33756327/1_14659377_33756327_120x90_b_1:2.jpg
                        [medium] => http://static-cdn2.ustream.tv/videopic/0/1/33/33756/33756327/1_14659377_33756327_320x240_b_1:2.jpg
                    )

                [sourceChannel] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 14659377
                        [url] => http://www.ustream.tv/channel/14659377
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 33756481
                [userName] => sachintaware
                [title] => gobiggitest
                [protected] => 
                [description] => gobiggitest
                [createdAt] => 2013-06-03 03:37:49
                [rating] => 0.000
                [lengthInSecond] => 647.580
                [totalViews] => 11
                [codecIsForLiveHttp] => 
                [url] => http://www.ustream.tv/recorded/33756481
                [embedTag] => 
                [liveHttpUrl] => 
                [imageUrl] => Array
                    (
                        [small] => http://static-cdn2.ustream.tv/videopic/0/1/33/33756/33756481/1_14659377_33756481_120x90_b_1:3.jpg
                        [medium] => http://static-cdn2.ustream.tv/videopic/0/1/33/33756/33756481/1_14659377_33756481_320x240_b_1:3.jpg
                    )

                [sourceChannel] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 14659377
                        [url] => http://www.ustream.tv/channel/14659377
                    )

            )
```

This is the function I used to go through the array as I want to fetch the `[id] => 14659377` which is inside `sourceChannel`.But I am getting an empty value as a return value.What is the mistake I am making? can anyone please help me with it?

```
$getUsername = array();
function recursion($array) {
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
      if($key==='sourceChannel'){
            $getId = $value['id'];
            //print_r($getId);
            return $getId;
          }
      if (is_array($value))
         recursion($value);
     }
}

$getUsername=recursion($resultsArray);
print_r($getUsername);
```

Comment: What's wrong with using `$array['results'][0]['sourceChannel']['id']`?

Comment: Why is your code actually starting with `$getUsername = array();` !? $getUsername is overwritten later and nothing is done with it in between...

Comment: @nl-x its a block of code and some lines exist as I have been trying out things with it! :P

Answer (score 12):

Your code is flawed because you need to change

```
recursion($value);
```

into

```
return recursion($value);
```

The return will take the answer back to the caller until the first caller is reached.

**edit:**
The lesson here is that your function should ALWAYS return a value. So here is some more elaboration:

```
function recursion($array) {
    if (!is_array($array)) // check if what you're getting is an array!
        return null;
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if($key==='sourceChannel') {
            return $value['id'];
        }
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $result = recursion($value);
            if ($result !== null) {
                return $result;
            }
        }
    }
    return null; // this happens if all recursions are done and sourceChannel was not found
}
```

Comment: This doesnt work because you're blindly returning the first recursion you try in the loop. You should only be returning if your recursion call actually returns a non-null value - otherwise we want to continue through the loop. See my answer for a complete fix.

Comment: I also missed 'return' syntax right before calling rec function again. Thanks.

Comment: return recursion() worked for me like a charm. Thanks @nl-x

Comment: oh! you are a life saver. return worked like a charm!

Comment: This doesn't tally with PHP documentation, which indicates that recursive functions work without explicitly returning a value: [PHP: User-defined functions - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php)

Comment: @osullic They totally work without explicitly returning a value. They just don't return a value.  The recursion in the code in question was being executed, but just didn't return the results.

Answer (score 2):

You're not doing anything with the return from your recursion call.
It's a bit more complex than simply returning it, because you only want to cascade out if we actually found anything.

Try this:

```
function recursion($array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if($key==='sourceChannel') {
            return $value['id'];
        }
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $rc = recursion($value);
            if (!is_null($rc)) return $rc;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

First, I added `return null;` to the end of the function - if we didn't find anything, we return null.

Then, when I recurse, I check the return value... if it's non-null, it means we found something and we want to return it. If it is null, we *don't* want to return - we want to continue the loop instead.

Comment: There's a `return null;` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
foreach ($array['results'] as $key => $value) {
   if($key == "sourceChannel"){
        $getId = $value['id'];
        //print_r($getId);
        return $getId;
   }       
}
```

Comment: This answer might suit this case. But doesn't have recursion, and thus does not really answer the question. `Why doesn't this PHP recursive function return the value?`

Comment: Why iterate over the array if you can also use `isset()`? And what happened to the recursive step?

Comment: Depends on what is to be expected. For now it would do. But then FDL's comment will even be better... `$array['results'][0]['sourceChannel']['id']`

Comment: It doesn't work,I believe I will need to modify my function call like this... `$getUsername=recursion($resultsArray['results']);` right? but still I get an error for either index 'result' or foreach argument! where am I wrong?

Comment: call like $getUsername=recursion($resultsArray); only

Comment: `'sourceChannel'` is not a key in `$array['results']`, so this code will never return anything other than undefined.

Comment: Then what will be the 'sourceChannel'..??

Answer (score 1):

You could use iterators to make your function a whole lot easier:

```
function findSourceChannel($array)
{
    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array)) as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == 'sourceChannel') {
            return $value['id'];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

That said, I'm not sure why you can't just do a search like this:

```
foreach ($array['results'] as $result) {
    if (isset($result['sourceChannel'])) {
        return $result['sourceChannel']['id'];
    }
}
return null;
```

Comment: Hey,thanks Jack are these classes inbuilt with the PHP version?Can I directly use them?Haven't tried them yet.

Comment: yup Jack that search did the trick.Also,if `sourceChannel` is not a `key`(as you said in the above post) in the array how can I do it using the `RecursiveIteratorIterator` method?

Comment: @coderunner In the meantime I've expanded my answer to include a method that doesn't even need recursion. Do check that out.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned in the previous post that it works and I just didn't think about it!!